# Presenting full screen "modal" loading view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit

My app's view hierarchy has a root `UINavigationController`, inside of which lives a `UIViewController` sub class containing a `UIWebView`. As soon as the app launches I wish to hide the entire Navigation Controller view with a full screen loading view controller, until the web view finish loading delegate method is called.

To achieve this I've considered one of two ways, neither of which "feel right":

- Add a subview to the `UINavigationController` view - this feels very hacky to meddle with the view of a Navigation Controller
- Present a modal view controller from the root level - I have to wait until `viewDidAppear` before calling this which causes an ugly flash of the lower VC before displaying. In turn, the loading VC in certain circumstances presents its own modal which means I'd have a modal on top of a modal on top of the root VC.

Am I going totally mad or is that not a particularly easy way to achieve this app flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat "elegant" approach: Create a shared singleton class containing the UIWebView that needs to be loaded and launch a request upon starting the app. Meanwhile, show the preloader screen (first thing that is added to the navigation stack when application launches). Once the request finishes loading, post a notification via the NSNotification center that causes the AppDelegate to push/switch to the loaded UIWebView controller.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution to "share" the web view between UIViewControllers and swap out the window's rootViewController at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for you to completely hide what's going on in the background with the UIWebView? Isn't a blocking activity indicator enough to achieve this user experience? If so, I would recommend using one of many nice activity indication components available online, such as [MBProgressHUD](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mbprogresshud)

Comment: To be honest, I agree with you - but I am attempting to implement a clients' design which has requested a full screen holding graphic (basically a UIViewController that replicates what Default.png looks like for a graceful transition during setup).

Comment: Clients will be the end of us... Make sure he knows that "graceful" can't be achieved this way :) You could add a subview to your [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow - make sure you do this before pushing the view controller (because this will obstruct the navigation animation, this might look ugly but you could add it as a subview and then animate it's position/alpha to make it look a bit better). Make sure you save a reference to it so you can dismiss it once your web view finishes loading

Comment: Spooky, this is where my thinking has moved since reading your last comment! My concern about this has always been having more than one view controller in play - though if this loading VC is intentionally blocking visibility of the other, is this realistically a concern?

Comment: My understanding regarding the whole (pre-iOS5 containers) is that it's 1x ViewController per "screen". Any more than this and the responder stack gets screwy not knowing which VC to report events to. That said if I make the true root window.rootViewController, anything else I stick (temporarily) in the subview of UIWindow can happily appear, do it's thing, and go again without causing issues elsewhere?

Comment: As I suspected, the loading VC isn't responding to rotation events etc. so it just looks weird.

Comment: I do not agree with the former comment, though we do need to figure a way to do this without using the application's main window. How about trying to add to the root view controller? Not the best practice, I agree, but this does require a workaround. You can get an easy reference to the root view controller via the AppDelegate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7454/discussion-between-andybee-and-stavash)